# Implementing stack backtrace in c

Tags: c

I want to implement stack_back-trace function in c using reading all the values stored on the stack! My problem is that, I can read the base pointer and return address for the current function but I don't know how I should skip the arguments above the return address to reach the next base pointer and return address!
In the following example, I can read bp2 and ret_add2 but I don't know how I should skip the passed arguments to the function (by adding a specific amount to bp2 ) to read bp1 and ret_add1!Can any body help me to solve this problem?

arg1

arg2

ret_add1

bp1

arg1

arg2

ret_add2

bp2

stack top

Thanks

Comment: What compiler/os are you trying to do this on?

Comment: Out of interest, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it and explain more (why, on which system, etc...)

Answer (score 4):

This is [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific. In practice depends upon the target processor, the compiler, the operating system. For Linux/x86-64 read its [ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf)

With GNU libc, you could use its [backtrace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) function (then perhaps [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) to find symbols near return addresses).

Otherwise, code something in assembler (it would be ABI & processor specific), perhaps as `asm` instructions inside some C function.

In general, you cannot even do that, e.g. because the compiler is free to make *internal* calls which are not following the ABI spec. Like when using the `-fomit-frame-pointer` flag on some processors with GCC.

Look also at Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libbacktrace) (it takes profit from [DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug info when available); perhaps GCC [return address builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) might be helpful. See also [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

BTW, be aware that some C compilers are able to do [tail call optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), and many are able to do [inline expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) (even without the `inline` keyword). In both cases, your question becomes moot.